Fan control app (speed and RGB) for MSI MAG + Lian Li case
I have built a PC for my son with MSI mag B650 Tomahawk motherboard and Lian Li Lancool 216 case.
From what I see, MSI and Lian Li, both have their own software to manage fan speed and RGB (Windows 11). My question is which one should I pick? Or maybe something else like https://getfancontrol.com/ + https://signalrgb.com/ ?
